# What causes 'Undefined property' error in Student controller and how to resolve it with Student_model?

Tags: php

Please help me fix this error -

> Undefined property: App\Controllers\Student::$StudentModel
> Student_model Student::$StudentModel

I followed the video and this is the code for Student controller but got an error saying
"Undefined property: App\Controllers\Student::$StudentModel"

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\Student_model;

 
class Student extends BaseController
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->StudentModel = new Student_model();
    }
   
    public function index()
    { 
        $data['student_info'] = $this ->StudentModel -> getStudentInfo();
        
        $data['Title'] = 'ITEC 222 Title';
        $data['Header'] = 'This is the new header';
        echo view('template/header', $data);
        echo view('student/index', $data);
        echo view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `StudentModel` should be `Student_model` or vice versa.

Comment: Paste your `Student_Model` class

Comment: Did you see this error in the editor or during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

```
Undefined property: App\Controllers\Student::$StudentModel
```

You're calling `$this->StudentModel = new Student_model();`. This error suggests the variable `$StudentModel` doesn't exist in either this class or the parent `BaseController`. If it does exist in `BaseController` then it's set to **private** and should be either **public** or **protected**. If it doesn't exist in either class then you need to add it.

Either (access modifier will depend on your use case)

```
class BaseController
{
    protected/public $StudentModel;
    ...
}
```

OR

```
class class Student extends BaseController
{
    protected/private/public $StudentModel;
    ...
}
```

Basically you can't call `$this->{variable}` if ${variable} doesn't exist or the class doesn't know about it (private in the parent).

Comment: Also if your version of php allows strict typing you can give the variable a type too.
protected/private/public Student_model $StudentModel;

Comment: ohh thank you i tried the last one using private and it worked ^^